# std::set::find vs std::find on std::set with const

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a little (working) test code but I do not understand why in the `test1` function I can only pass a `int* const` as parameter while in the `test2` function I can pass a `const int*`. If I pass a `const int*` to `test1`, I get a discard qualifier error.

In my research, I found that both `std::find` and `set::find` have a const version so I can't see why they behave differently. I also tried with `boost::container::flat_set` instead of a `std::set` and I got the same result.
Could someone explain me please?

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass() {};
    ~myClass() {};

    void add(int* ref)
    {
        this->_ref.insert(ref);
    };

    bool test1(int* const ref) const
    {
        return ( this->_ref.find(ref) != this->_ref.end() );
    }

    inline
    bool test2(const int* ref) const
    {
        return ( std::find(this->_ref.begin(), this->_ref.end(), ref) != this->_ref.end() );
    }

    std::set<int*> _ref;
};

int main()
{
    myClass test;
    test.add(new int(18));
    test.add(new int(35));
    test.add(new int(78));
    test.add(new int(156));

    std::cout<<test.test1(0)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<test.test1(*test._ref.begin())<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<test.test2(0)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<test.test2(*test._ref.begin())<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::set::find` expects `const value_type&` which gives you `int* const&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container `std::set<int*>` has only *homogeneous* lookup, so you can only search keys by comparing them with a value *of the same type*: `find`, `count`, `erase`. Naturally, a value of type `const int*` does not have the same type as `int*`, so your `test2` code attempts to convert the former to the latter, which is not an allowed conversion.

The fact that containers could only be used in a homogeneous way like that has been a shortcoming of C++ since inception, and more egregrious examples of undesired conversions are when you have a map with `std::string` keys and want to look up an element with a key provided as a string literal. You always have to construct the dynamic `std::string` object, even though `std::string` provide comparisons operators with string literals.

Therefore, since C++14, you can also make a set (or map) with inhomogeneous lookup by spelling it `std::set<int*, std::less<>>`. With such a container, the loopup functions become templates, and you can indeed compare values of different types (leaving the conversion logic to the underlying `<`-operator). But note that `std::less<int*>` is required to provide a strict weak ordering on pointers, whereas `std::less<>` is not, so you may end up with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh ok, I see! So a last question: is it less performant in the case of std::find because of the implicit conversion of type? (without regarding the optimizations due to the specialized set::find function)

Comment: @user52730: I don't understand - is *what* less performant than what?

Comment: I mean: does the conversion of type when using std:find induces a CPU cost compared to the case of set::find where no conversion is needed? Or is it solved at compile time?

Comment: @user52730: Ah, I see. `std::find` is a template and doesn't perform conversions, either. It uses the inhomogeneous comparison. Of course it also performs linear search rather than binary search.

Answer (score 4):

`set::find()` gives the answer in O(logN) while `std::find()` gives the answer in O(N) .

Similarly, `map::find()` gives the answer in O(logN) while `std::find()` gives the answer in O(N) .